# Using ngforce for logging out user

Tags: javascript, salesforce-sdk-hybrid, logout

I am using force ng library for one of my hybrid apps, but issue is I cannot find any method to log out users so that different credentials can be used.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [revoke](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_revoke_token.htm&language=en) to log out. [forceng](https://github.com/ccoenraets/forceng) doesn't have a method baked into it, but it's really just as simple as using angularjs' [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to call the appropriate endpoint.

Comment: great will check this out.!!

Answer (score 0):

forceng doesn't have the method to logout but you can write custom method to logout using SalesforceSDK

```
function logout(){

  var sfOAuthPlugin  = cordova.require("com.salesforce.plugin.oauth");
  sfOAuthPlugin.logout();
}
```

This method logouts current user.It will securly loggedout the user and flush the stored access and refresh token